# Generating data averages for 15min slots using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an SQL Server table as below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChannelData](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ChannelId] [int] NOT NULL,
[ChannelValue] [decimal](10, 2) NULL,
[ChannelDataLogTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Active] [bit] NULL,CONSTRAINT [PK_ChannelData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ( [Id] ASC )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Sample Data is as follows:::

```
+----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Id | ChannelId | ChannelValue |   ChannelDataLogTime    | Active |
+----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
|  1 |         9 |         5.46 | 2015-06-09 14:00:11.463 |      1 |
|  2 |         9 |         8.46 | 2015-06-09 14:01:11.503 |      1 |
|  3 |         9 |         3.46 | 2015-06-09 14:02:27.747 |      1 |
|  4 |         9 |         6.46 | 2015-06-09 14:03:11.503 |      1 |
|  5 |         9 |         1.46 | 2015-06-09 14:04:11.530 |      1 |
|  6 |         9 |         4.46 | 2015-06-09 14:05:11.537 |      1 |
|  7 |         9 |         7.46 | 2015-06-09 14:06:11.547 |      1 |
|  8 |         9 |         2.46 | 2015-06-09 14:07:33.983 |      1 |
|  9 |         9 |         5.46 | 2015-06-09 14:08:11.570 |      1 |
| 10 |         9 |         8.46 | 2015-06-09 14:09:11.603 |      1 |
| 11 |         9 |         3.46 | 2015-06-09 14:10:11.613 |      1 |
| 12 |         9 |         6.47 | 2015-06-09 14:11:11.623 |      1 |
| 13 |         9 |         1.47 | 2015-06-09 14:12:24.497 |      1 |
| 14 |         9 |         4.47 | 2015-06-09 14:13:11.623 |      1 |
| 15 |         9 |         7.47 | 2015-06-09 14:14:11.650 |      1 |
| 16 |         9 |         2.47 | 2015-06-09 14:15:11.707 |      1 |
| 17 |         9 |         5.47 | 2015-06-09 14:16:11.707 |      1 |
| 18 |         9 |         8.47 | 2015-06-09 14:17:25.647 |      1 |
| 19 |         9 |         3.47 | 2015-06-09 14:18:11.707 |      1 |
| 20 |         9 |         6.47 | 2015-06-09 14:19:11.753 |      1 |
| 21 |         9 |         1.47 | 2015-06-09 14:20:11.760 |      1 |
| 22 |         9 |         4.47 | 2015-06-09 14:21:11.790 |      1 |
| 23 |         9 |         7.47 | 2015-06-09 14:22:29.500 |      1 |
| 24 |         9 |         2.47 | 2015-06-09 14:23:11.907 |      1 |
| 25 |         9 |         5.47 | 2015-06-09 14:24:12.057 |      1 |
| 26 |         9 |         8.47 | 2015-06-09 14:25:11.817 |      1 |
| 27 |         9 |         3.47 | 2015-06-09 14:26:11.837 |      1 |
| 28 |         9 |         6.47 | 2015-06-09 14:27:32.253 |      1 |
| 29 |         9 |         1.47 | 2015-06-09 14:28:11.870 |      1 |
| 30 |         9 |         4.47 | 2015-06-09 14:29:11.870 |      1 |
| 31 |         9 |         7.50 | 2015-06-09 16:00:13.313 |      1 |
| 32 |         9 |         2.50 | 2015-06-09 16:01:13.260 |      1 |
| 33 |         9 |         5.50 | 2015-06-09 16:02:13.290 |      1 |
| 34 |         9 |         8.50 | 2015-06-09 16:03:13.270 |      1 |
| 35 |         9 |         3.50 | 2015-06-09 16:04:32.827 |      1 |
| 36 |         9 |         6.50 | 2015-06-09 16:05:13.323 |      1 |
| 37 |         9 |         1.50 | 2015-06-09 16:06:13.330 |      1 |
| 38 |         9 |         4.50 | 2015-06-09 16:07:13.337 |      1 |
| 39 |         9 |         7.50 | 2015-06-09 16:08:13.313 |      1 |
| 40 |         9 |         2.50 | 2015-06-09 16:09:28.497 |      1 |
| 41 |         9 |         5.50 | 2015-06-09 16:10:13.370 |      1 |
| 42 |         9 |         8.50 | 2015-06-09 16:11:13.417 |      1 |
| 43 |         9 |         3.50 | 2015-06-09 16:12:13.540 |      1 |
| 44 |         9 |         6.50 | 2015-06-09 16:13:13.577 |      1 |
| 45 |         9 |         1.50 | 2015-06-09 16:14:33.880 |      1 |
| 46 |         9 |         4.50 | 2015-06-09 16:15:13.453 |      1 |
| 47 |         9 |         7.50 | 2015-06-09 16:16:13.500 |      1 |
| 48 |         9 |         2.50 | 2015-06-09 16:17:13.497 |      1 |
| 49 |         9 |         5.50 | 2015-06-09 16:18:13.503 |      1 |
| 50 |         9 |         8.50 | 2015-06-09 16:19:38.717 |      1 |
| 51 |         9 |         3.50 | 2015-06-09 16:21:13.567 |      1 |
| 52 |         9 |         6.50 | 2015-06-09 16:22:13.557 |      1 |
| 53 |         9 |         1.50 | 2015-06-09 16:23:14.163 |      1 |
| 54 |         9 |         4.50 | 2015-06-09 16:24:13.607 |      1 |
| 55 |         9 |         7.50 | 2015-06-09 16:25:38.783 |      1 |
| 56 |         9 |         2.50 | 2015-06-09 16:27:13.660 |      1 |
| 57 |         9 |         5.51 | 2015-06-09 16:28:13.710 |      1 |
| 58 |         9 |         8.51 | 2015-06-09 16:29:13.703 |      1 |
| 59 |         9 |         3.51 | 2015-06-09 16:30:13.713 |      1 |
+----+-----------+--------------+-------------------------+--------+
```

Now I am generating 15 minute averaged data for a period of time, with start date and end date. Which is working fine with out any issues.

I have scenario where the data will be missing for some time. Which inturn missing the 15 minute slots as there is no data for that 15min slot. What I need is to list the 15 minute slots even if the data is not available during that time slot using SQL Query.

```
SELECT
                            Avg(chnldata.ChannelValue)  AS ChannelValue,
                            DATEADD(minute,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(minute,0,ChannelDataLogTime)/15)*15,0) as HourlyDateTime,
                           chnldata.ChannelId as Id
                    FROM ChannelData as chnldata
                    WHERE  chnldata.ChannelId in (9) AND chnldata.ChannelDataLogTime >= '06/09/2015'  AND chnldata.ChannelDataLogTime < '06/11/2015 23:59:50' 
                     GROUP BY chnldata.ChannelId, DATEADD(minute,FLOOR(DATEDIFF(minute,0,ChannelDataLogTime)/15)*15,0)
```

This is the existing 15 min average query. But it doesn't display missing 15min slots.
The current output is:::

```
+--------------+-------------------------+----+
| ChannelValue |     HourlyDateTime      | Id |
+--------------+-------------------------+----+
|     5.129333 | 2015-06-09 14:00:00.000 |  9 |
|     4.803333 | 2015-06-09 14:15:00.000 |  9 |
|     5.033333 | 2015-06-09 16:00:00.000 |  9 |
|     5.270769 | 2015-06-09 16:15:00.000 |  9 |
|     3.510000 | 2015-06-09 16:30:00.000 |  9 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----+
```

Required Output is:::

```
+--------------+-------------------------+----+
| ChannelValue |     HourlyDateTime      | Id |
+--------------+-------------------------+----+
| 5.129333     | 2015-06-09 14:00:00.000 |  9 |
| 4.803333     | 2015-06-09 14:15:00.000 |  9 |
| NULL         | 2015-06-09 14:30:00.000 |  9 |
| NULL         | 2015-06-09 14:45:00.000 |  9 |
| NULL         | 2015-06-09 15:00:00.000 |  9 |
| NULL         | 2015-06-09 15:15:00.000 |  9 |
| NULL         | 2015-06-09 15:30:00.000 |  9 |
| NULL         | 2015-06-09 15:45:00.000 |  9 |
| 5.033333     | 2015-06-09 16:00:00.000 |  9 |
| 5.270769     | 2015-06-09 16:15:00.000 |  9 |
| 3.510000     | 2015-06-09 16:30:00.000 |  9 |
+--------------+-------------------------+----+
```

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide a sample data and expected results as _formatted text_ please?

Comment: Should not be the 'Id' field be null in the interval without data?

Answer (score 1):

RIGHT OUTER JOIN to a CTE that has all the possible 15-minute intervals in your time-range.

Answer (score 0):

build a time range CTE, which can be done in various ways, but the cartesian product method is probably faster than many methods
if you want speed it might be best to build a static dates table and maybe a dates and a time table

```
;WITH mins as (SELECT 0 as q union select 15 union select 30 union select 45),
      dats as (SELECT MIN(ChannelDataLogTime) as t1, max(ChannelDataLogTime) as t2 from channeldata),
      ranges as (SELECT CAST(t1 as date) s1 FROM dats
                union all
                SELECT dateadd(day,1,r.s1) from ranges r where r.s1< (select t2 from dats)
                ),
      hrs as (select 0 h union all select  h + 1 from hrs where h < 23),    --hours 0 to 23
      slots as (select dateadd(MINUTE,mins.q,dateadd(hour,hrs.h,cast(ranges.s1 as datetime2))) as strt from mins,ranges,hrs      ),
      ids as (SELECT distinct  ChannelId from  ChannelData),
      allslot as (select channelid, strt from slots,ids)
        SELECT    count(0) as x,
                            coalesce(Avg(chnldata.ChannelValue)   , 0) AS ChannelValue,
                            s.strt HourlyDateTime,
                           s.ChannelId as Id
                    FROM ChannelData as chnldata
                    RIGHT JOIN  allslot s on s.strt <= ChannelDataLogTime and ChannelDataLogTime < dateadd(minute,15,s.strt) and s.ChannelId = chnldata.ChannelId 
                    WHERE  chnldata.ChannelId is null or chnldata.ChannelId in (9) AND chnldata.ChannelDataLogTime >= '20150906'  AND chnldata.ChannelDataLogTime < '20151123' 
                     GROUP BY s.ChannelId, s.strt
```

Answer (score 0):

Take in consideration the limitations of maxrecursion option.

```
DECLARE @StartDT DATETIME = '2015-06-09';
DECLARE @EndDT DATETIME = '2015-06-12'; -- moved to the next day to use >= and < operators correctly

;WITH
[Interval]
AS
(
    SELECT
         [Start] = @StartDT
        ,[End] = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, @StartDT)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
         [Start] = [End]
        ,[End] = DATEADD(MINUTE, 15, [End])
    FROM [Interval]
    WHERE (1 = 1)
        AND ([End] < @EndDT)
),
[Available]
AS
(
    SELECT
         [Start] = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, MIN([CD].[ChannelDataLogTime]))
        ,[End] = CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, MAX([CD].[ChannelDataLogTime]))
    FROM [dbo].[ChannelData] AS [CD]
    WHERE (1 = 1)
        AND (@StartDT <= [CD].[ChannelDataLogTime] AND [CD].[ChannelDataLogTime] < @EndDT)
)
SELECT
     [ChannelValue] = AVG([CD].[ChannelValue])
    ,[HourlyDateTime] = [I].[Start]
    ,[Id] = [CD].[ChannelId]
FROM [Available] AS [A]
INNER JOIN [Interval] AS [I]
    ON ([A].[Start] <= [I].[Start] AND [I].[Start] <= [A].[End])
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[ChannelData] AS [CD]
    ON
    (
            ([CD].[ChannelId] IN (9))
        AND ([I].[Start] <= [CD].[ChannelDataLogTime] AND [CD].[ChannelDataLogTime] < [I].[End])
    )
GROUP BY
     [I].[Start]
    ,[CD].[ChannelId]
ORDER BY
     [I].[Start]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```